# Create Auto-TOC based on document type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to get a table of contents page to show and update automatically based on a document type.

What we currently have is a txt file which we have to manually update.

Basically - we have a top level of "Service Desk Knowledge Database" and then the next levels are "Environment", "Applications", "System Access", "Applications", "Hardware".

Under each of these headings we have documents which all have a document type.

For instance, under "Applications" we have MS Outlook, Citrix, SAP etc.

What I need is when I click "Applications" I want to see an alphabetised list of the documents with a type of "Application" which the users can view and then click into.

I can't see where I can do this easily.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Using Sharepoint 2010

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Connected Web Parts may be what you are looking for.  Microsoft has a good high level example of this [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA010024105.aspx).